# Network monitor crashing in iOS13

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

So I am trying to keep my current up at iOS 13 + while bring in a few iOS 14 features.
One of the new features is monitoring if a user loses network connection.

However I am getting a strange error when I run the following code.

TaView.swift (default view)

```
import SwiftUI


struct TaView: View {
    @StateObject var monitor = Monitor()
    @ObservedObject var location = LocationManager()
    @State var errorDetail = false
  
    
    var lat: String{
        return "\(location.lastKnownLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.0)"
    }
    
    var lon: String{
        return "\(location.lastKnownLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.0)"
    }
    
    var state: String{
        return "\(UserSettings().state)"
    }
    
    init() {
//        print(self.data.connected)
        self.location.startUpdating()
    }
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        if (self.lat == "0.0" && self.lon == "0.0"){
            LocationDisabled()
        }
        else{
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                TabView {
                    ContentView()
                        
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "dot.radiowaves.left.and.right")
                            Text("Radio")
                        }
                    
                    WinView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "w.circle")
                            Text("Win")
                        }
                    
                    SettingsView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                            Text("Settings")
                            
                        }
                }.accentColor(Color.red)
                .onAppear(){
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
                        if monitor.score == 0{
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
                                self.errorDetail = true
                            }
                        }
                        
                        //print("this is the score \(monitor.score)")
                    }
                }
                .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$errorDetail, content: NetworkOutageView.init)
            } else {
                TabView {
                    ContentView()
                        
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "dot.radiowaves.left.and.right")
                            Text("Radio")
                        }
                    
                    WinView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "w.circle")
                            Text("Win")
                        }
                    
                    SettingsView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "gear")
                            Text("Settings")
                            
                        }
                }.accentColor(Color.red)
                .onAppear(){
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
                        if monitor.score == 0{
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
                                self.errorDetail = true
                            }
                        }
                        
                        //print("this is the score \(monitor.score)")
                    }
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$errorDetail, content: NetworkOutageView.init)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct LocationDisabled: View {
    @ObservedObject var location = LocationManager()

    init() {
        self.location.startUpdating()
    }
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
        VStack{
            Spacer().frame(maxHeight: 100)
            Image(systemName: "location.fill").resizable().scaledToFit().frame(width: 100).foregroundColor(Color.white)
            
            VStack{
                 Text("Enable Location").font(.system(.largeTitle, design: .rounded)).bold().multilineTextAlignment(.leading).foregroundColor(Color.white)
                 Text("You'll need to enable your location.\nIn order to use access these features").fontWeight(.light).multilineTextAlignment(.center).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true).padding(.all, 8).foregroundColor(Color.white)
                 Text("\u{2022} Win Prizes\n\n\u{2022} Change Stations\n\n\u{2022} Access Podcasts\n\n\u{2022} Request Songs\n\n\u{2022} And More").bold().multilineTextAlignment(.center).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true).padding(.all, 8).foregroundColor(Color.white)
                 
                
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                     self.location.requestLoc()
                }) {
                    Text("ALLOW LOCATION")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .bold()
                }.buttonStyle(LocationGradientButtonStyle())
                .padding(.bottom, 100)
           }
        
        
        
       // ImageOverlay()
    }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all).background(
        Image("TooFarWallPaper").resizable().aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill).frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        )
    }
    }
}


struct LocationGradientButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some SwiftUI.View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding()
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.purple]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
            .cornerRadius(15.0)
    }
}

struct SaveGradientButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some SwiftUI.View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .padding()
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.green, Color.green]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
            .cornerRadius(15.0)
    }
}
```

Monitor.swift

```
import Network
import SwiftUI

// An enum to handle the network status
enum NetworkStatus: String {
    case connected
    case disconnected
}

class Monitor: ObservableObject {
    private let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    private let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Monitor")

    @Published var score = 0
    @Published var status: NetworkStatus = .connected
  
    init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            // Monitor runs on a background thread so we need to publish
            // on the main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if path.status == .satisfied {
                    print("We're connected!")
                    self.status = .connected
                    self.score = 1
                  

                } else {
                    print("No connection.")
                    self.score = 0
                    self.status = .disconnected
                }
            }
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
}
```

The error is

`Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`

I am wondering how do I fix this?

[image: error with Monitor.]

Comment: I can not reproduce this error, are you running on `Simulator`, this is working fine for me, tested on `iOS 14.4` and `Xcode 12.4`

Comment: yes it works fine for iOS14+ but not iOS 13.6

Comment: Note that this code can't work on `iOS 13.6` since you are using the `@StateObject` property wrapper which is available from `iOS 14.0` and above.

Comment: Try using `@ObservedObject` instead.

Comment: So wonder what is the solution to fix this to make it backwards compatible

Comment: Couldn't test on `iOS 13.6` but changing `@StateObject` to `ObservedObject`works great on `iOS 13.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

Changing `@StateObject` to `ObservedObject` works great.

Note: you don't always need to write the same code again in `if` and `else` when checking for `@availability` (when doing backwards compatibility), you can just create one single variable for a `View` and reuse it, like in this case we reuse `tabViewContent`.

```
struct TaView: View {
    @ObservedObject var monitor = Monitor()
    
    @ObservedObject var location = LocationManager()
    @State var errorDetail = false
    
    
    var lat: String{
        return "\(location.lastKnownLocation?.coordinate.latitude ?? 0.0)"
    }
    
    var lon: String{
        return "\(location.lastKnownLocation?.coordinate.longitude ?? 0.0)"
    }
    
    var state: String{
        return "\(UserSettings().state)"
    }
    
    init() {
        //        print(self.data.connected)
        self.location.startUpdating()
    }
    @ObservedObject var userSettings = UserSettings()
    
    var tabViewContent: some View {
        TabView {
            ContentView()
                
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "dot.radiowaves.left.and.right")
                    Text("Radio")
                }
            
            WinView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "w.circle")
                    Text("Win")
                }
            
            SettingsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "gear")
                    Text("Settings")
                    
                }
        }.accentColor(Color.red)
        .onAppear(){
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { (timer) in
                if monitor.score == 0{
                    self.errorDetail = true
                } else {
                    self.errorDetail = false
                    
                }
                
                //print("this is the score \(monitor.score)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if (self.lat == "0.0" && self.lon == "0.0"){
            LocationDisabled()
        }
        else{
            if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
                tabViewContent
                    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$errorDetail, content: NetworkOutageView.init)
            } else {
                tabViewContent
                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$errorDetail, content: NetworkOutageView.init)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with `Xcode 12.4`, on `iOS13.3.1` and `iOS 14.4.2`